# Absolute reference with R1C1 using a variable to dictat row number (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that creates a number of separate lists under each other. For each of these lists I'm running a for loop to assign an equation to each row at the end column. This formula should multiply the neighbour cell (a relative reference) with cell at the top of that particular list (an absolute referance). The problem is that the lists are of arbitrary length and generated earlier in the code, so I can't assign the absolute referance beforhand.

I was thinking on saving the row number (row 1 = 1, row 2 = 2 etc) in a variable and then use the variable in the R1C1 notation (= "R(variable)C5*RC[-1]), but I cant seem to get this to work... The variable will be the same throughout the for loop given in the example below, but will change next time the same for loop is entered.

**Is this even possible?**

(I know the parantheses in the R1C1 are not the proper notation, but this is to show where I want my variable)

```
...
variable = 3

For i = 1 to count

last = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(siste, "E").FormulaR1C1 = "=R(variable)C5*RC[-1]"

Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one small change:

```
Cells(siste, "E").FormulaR1C1 = "=R" & variable & "C5*RC[-1]"
```